# Lottie animation crashes on "needsUpdate"?

Tags: swift, lottie

I am trying to use Lottie animations. I am getting a crash, I am not sure what I am doing wrong yet.

My code is this:

[image]

When I run this, the crash triggers when the line "starAnimationView.animation = startAnimation" is run.

Xcode shows this:
[image: tie]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I crash too.

So, I changed swift package manager to Carthage.

And crush was resolved.